Quick link to BrickSet or similar set database
Don't we want or can implement quick links to any set database, e.g. BrickSet.com, to make linking set ids more handy?
P.S.
I've just published a small Firefox search plugin for the same purpose.

I've added this into my POC for parts: http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/62/code-to-insert-parts

@Zhaph: Thanks! Maybe post it as an answer to accept it?

Consider it done :)

I'm sure it's possible to implement (perhaps using the word filter), I'd certainly find it very helpful.
Something like this?
[bs:5590]

Links to set 5590 on Brickset and...
[bl:5590]

...links to the same set but on Bricklink. Linking to pieces would be helpful too.

I could help to implement that as being a programmer, with pleasure. I thing RegEx filter "only digits, 4 or 5 symbols long" will be enough, will it not?

The key thing is the brackets and identifier. See the work Kevin did on the part image links we've also proposed.

Perhaps I could be of assistance here?

@Ambo100 the code I'm looking to get added for part images already does linking to parts, I'll try and add this in - my concern here is that BrickSet for example adds additional identifiers on to the set number. See the work here http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/62/code-to-insert-parts

To clarify, would we be happy linking to the primary set with this? For example, the City Airport theme had a few "promotional" re-releases of some sets, that are listed as -2 of the same set number? http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=67.518.325

Feel free to come and join the discussion in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1741/bricks-se-parts-javascript-discussion to see what we've got so far and offer advice/assistance.

I've added this feature to the BrickJax code that can be seen here:

Code to insert parts

This is also available as a greasemonkey/user script linked from the same page.
